# Salesforce visualforce get CreatedBy field label

Tags: salesforce, translation, label

I'm creating a visualforce page that is ready for translations. I've been using ObjectType global variable to get field labels on the page. They work great, except for CreatedBy:

```
{!$ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.Fields.Name.Label}              // works
{!$ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.Fields.MyCustomField__c.Label}  // works
{!$ObjectType.MyCustomObject__c.Fields.CreatedBy.Label}         // doesn't work
```

How can I get the labels for this fields?

Answer (score 1):

There is no field called CreatedBy, you want either `CreatedById` for the user that made the change, or `CreatedByDate` for the timestamp of when the record was created

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that: CreatedById shows "Creator Id" (or something like that, I'm seeing it in spanish). CreatedByDate doesn't work, but CreatedDate does.